# How is a boolean a valid React.ReactNode value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How is a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`) not an invalid value for a prop of type `React.ReactNode`, resulting in the following being a Typescript error?

```
interface IProps {
    node: React.ReactNode;
}

const foo: IProps = {
    node: false,
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReactNode` represents all the possible values that can be put as a child of an element. Booleans are allowed because the following is a very common pattern for doing conditional rendering:

```
const condition: boolean = Math.random() > 0.5;

<div>
  {condition && (
    <p>You win!</p>
  )}
</div>
```

If `condition` is `false`, then the div's children prop will be `false`, and so the type is set up to allow this.

If you only want to allow elements, consider using `React.ReactElement` instead:

```
interface IProps {
   node: React.ReactElement;
}

const foo: IProps = {
  node: <div /> // Good
}

const foo2: IProps = {
  node: null // Error. If you want to allow null, change to React.ReactElement | null
}

const foo3: IProps = {
  node: false // Error
}
```